# Getting Object is possibly 'undefined' in typescript react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I am practicing typescript with react and fetching some data from an `API` I created a few days ago, API is working fine, am getting data for my front-end while fetching but when I try to use forEach or map method on that array of data it is throwing me an error:
`Object is possibly 'undefined'`

```
interface Posts {
  _id: string
  title: string
  date: string
  text: string
  author_name: string
  published: boolean
  __v: number
}

const TextField = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<Posts>()

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const result = await fetch("https://ed-blog-api.herokuapp.com/api/posts")
    const data = await result.json()
    const posts = data.posts
    setPosts(posts)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={fetchData}>Click</button>
      {posts.forEach((post: object) => {  // getting error here for posts
        console.log(post)
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: first off you have a naming conflict, naming `const posts = data.posts` and `[posts, setPosts] = useState<Posts>()`
Just do `setPosts(data.posts ?? [])` or something.
To get "rid" of the possibly undefined issue you can do `posts?.forEach((post) => console.log(post))`
Using the `?` operator the assertion will only be executed if posts is not undefined.

Comment: Also I'm unsure about your interface.
Shouldnt it be `Post` and "Posts" is `Post[]`, meaning it is an *array of posts*.
So you could simply initialize your posts as `[posts, setPosts] = useState<Post[]>([])`.
Then you could just use  `posts.map(post: Post => <div key={post._id}>Post works!</div>`
Using the "object" type is *strongly* discouraged, you should avoid doing that.

Comment: You can check out this link: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data.

Comment: Hey @Braks thanks your solution worked for me, please make this as answer so I can mark as answered thanks a lot again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `Posts` interface is actually the interface of a single `Post`

so:

```
interface Post {
  _id: string
  title: string
  date: string
  text: string
  author_name: string
  published: boolean
  __v: number
}

type Posts=Post[]
```

Now in here, you don't need to type `post` as `object` anymore. Typescript will infer it itself.

```
    const TextField = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<Posts|[]>([])

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const result = await fetch("https://ed-blog-api.herokuapp.com/api/posts")
    const data = await result.json()
    const posts = data.posts
    setPosts(posts)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={fetchData}>Click</button>
      {posts.forEach((post) => {  
        console.log(post)
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

But actually the reason of that error, is that in JavaScript the type of `null` is also object! so if you type anything as `object`, you are saying it could be an array, object or null. if it is null, you can't use any properties of it.

Answer (score 2):

**Response**

```
{
  "posts": [{
    "_id": "61514ba64209dbbaef9d05bb",
    "title": "Valorant Sucks",
    "date": "2021-09-27T04:40:05.001Z",
    "text": "Valorant Sucks a lot, everytime I got fuccking smurf, not even a single bullet registering and lots of bugs and bugs",
    "author_name": "Dev Chaudhary",
    "published": true,
    "__v": 0
  }]
}
```

as the response that you used, the `response.posts` is `Array`.

so you should do like this.

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState<Array<Posts>>([])
```

Futhermore,

```
return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={fetchData}>Click</button>
      {posts.forEach((post) => {  // you don't need to use `object` as type.        
        console.log(post)
      })}
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Full code

```
interface Posts {
  _id: string;
  title: string;
  date: string;
  text: string;
  author_name: string;
  published: boolean;
  __v: number;
}

const TextField = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<Posts[]>([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const result = await fetch('https://ed-blog-api.herokuapp.com/api/posts');
    const data = await result.json();
    const posts = data.posts;
    setPosts(posts);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={fetchData}>Click</button>
      {posts.map((post: Posts, index: number) => {
        // getting error here for posts
        console.log(post);
        return <div key={index}>{JSON.stringify(post)}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Make `posts` an array. Then you can solve the loop error.

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState<Posts[]>([]);
```

And I recommend to use `map` instead of `forEach`

```
{posts.map((post: Posts, index: number) => {
    console.log(post);
    return <div key={index}>{JSON.stringify(post)}</div>;
})}
```

or (If you simply want to output only the component)

```
{posts.map((post: Posts, index: number) => (
    <div key={index}>{JSON.stringify(post)}</div>
))}
```